# PDO UPDATE not working - syntax looks correct, PDO is set to throw exceptions

Tags: pdo, sql-update

When connecting to the database, I set PDO options as follows:

```
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT        => false,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES  => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE           => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
```

In the code, I initialize the asset type using the database information and then compare it to what the user has submitted to see if there need to be any changes:

```
$manufacturer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'manufacturer', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$model = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'model', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$fixed = isset($_POST['fixed']) ? TRUE : FALSE;
$asset_type_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'asset_type_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$asset_type->initialize($db, $asset_type_id);
$asset_type->update($db, $manufacturer, $model, $fixed);
```

The initialize(...) function gets the current information in the database and configures the object correctly...

```
function initialize(PDO $db, $asset_type_id){
    $this->asset_type_id = $asset_type_id;
    $asset_type_statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM asset_type WHERE id=:asset_type_id");
    $asset_type_statement->bindValue(':asset_type_id', $asset_type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $asset_type_statement->execute();
    $asset_type_result = $asset_type_statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ...
```

But the update(...) function is not working... no errors, but no updates either.

```
function update(PDO $db, $manufacturer, $model, $fixed) {
    try{
        if($this->manufacturer !== $manufacturer  || $this->model !== $model || $this->fixed != $fixed) {
            $update_asset_type_statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE asset_type SET manufacturer = :manufacturer, model = :model, fixed = :fixed WHERE id = :asset_type_id");
            $update_asset_type_statement->bindValue(':manufacturer', $manufacturer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $update_asset_type_statement->bindValue(':model', $model, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $update_asset_type_statement->bindValue(':fixed', $fixed, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
            $update_asset_type_statement->bindValue(':asset_type_id', $this->asset_type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $update_asset_type_statement->execute();
        }
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I've stepped through the code and all variables have the expected values.  I am at a loss.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: `$this->asset_type_id` where are you setting it?

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally removed that line from the top of the initialize function when cleaning up the code for posting it here. Added back now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing a comment at [Must Be Built](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/)
I changed the code to:

```
$update_asset_type_statement->bindValue(':fixed', $fixed, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update_asset_type_statement->bindValue(':asset_type_id', $this->asset_type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

And now it works - so my question is, why have PDO::PARAM_BOOL in the first place?

Comment: Does the SQL driver/server support BOOL datatype?

Comment: I did a little more digging and PDOStatement::execute treats all values as PDO::PARAM_STR see: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php so I guess you have to declare that they are all strings... except for the search parameter... apparently... I'm going to change that to as string as well though, just in case someone notices that it works and fixes it to match the documentation :P